# Trying to create a simple IF function in a script

Tags: google-sheets

What I'm trying to do is easily explained :
I have a google sheet containing product descriptions in column B. If the column description contains a certain string ("New", for example), there will not be any value in columns D, I and N.
I want to set up a quick script that will find the rows where the product description contains "New", and will put the value "Introduction Price" on this row in columns D, I and N.

I've made a start, but being pretty much entirely new to this I haven't really got very far yet :

```
function New() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetId").getSheetByName("Pricelist_Direct");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var irange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, row, 1);
  var drange = sheet.getRange(1, 4, row, 1);
  var data = irange.getValues();
  if(irange.match("New") {
    drange.setValue("Introduction Price")

  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate a pointer in the right direction. Thank you!